# How do I upload a custom emoji to my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js, emoji

I have made a discord bot and I would now like to get started on adding custom emojis. I have seen many tutorials on how to use client.cache or something to type an emoji, but how do I upload them and get their ID to use in my discord bot. I would appreciate a fast and easy answer!

<3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have to do is have your bot in a server with whichever emotes you want to use in your bot. Then, you type the emote with a backslash in front and send it, returning something like `<:honk:670458084136845352>`. That's what you put in the message for your bot.

If you have any issues, or this isn't clear enough, please let me know.

Comment: You can use the id of the emoji by itself, too. (<670458084136845352>)

Comment: Do I need Discord Nitro to use custom selfmade Emotes, or is there any way to use an image?

Comment: @FireFuro99 Bots are able to use custom emotes anywhere while normal users can only use them in the server where they were created.

Comment: @Dinty alright, thank you!